# Webcam has low FPS when recording using OpenCV?

Tags: java, opencv, webcam, frame-rate, latency

I've been working on building a Java application using OpenCV that grabs data from the webcam and records it. However, I've been unable to achieve frame rates greater than 10 FPS (Intel i5-5200u, 8 GB RAM), which doesn't seem right to me. My webcam supports up to 30 FPS and 1280 x 720 resolution. Recording at 640 x 480 only increases to about 12 FPS. Recording at 720p (which I need to do for my application) nets the aforementioned 10. My first idea was that the VideoCapture.read() function takes a relatively long time to process, so I tried moving those calls to a thread pool, but it gave no gain. I've read all about how fast this library is supposed to be, so I must be doing something wrong. Below is the loop for capturing data:

```
    VideoCapture cam = new VideoCapture();
    cam.open(0);

    // set proper resolution
    cam.set(Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CAMERA_WIDTH);
    cam.set(Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    // Matrix for storing camera images, provided by OpenCV
    ArrayList<Mat> framesList = new ArrayList<>();

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if( ! cam.isOpened()) {
        System.err.println("Camera could not be opened.");
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Capturing...");

        while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 1000 * SECONDS_TO_RUN) {

            Mat frame = new Mat();
            cam.read(frame);
            framesList.add(frame);

        }

        cam.release();

        System.out.println("Done recording. " + framesList.size() + " frames captured.");
        System.out.println("Framerate : " + framesList.size() / SECONDS_TO_RUN);
```

Comment: How many seconds do you perform this loop? can you remove the buffering:  framesList.add(frame); ?

Comment: @Micka, thanks for the reply. I've tried running for 5, 10, 30 seconds. All lengths give 8-10 FPS. And i'm sorry, I'm a little confused, what do you mean remove the buffering? As far as I'm aware, there is not another way to grab camera data besides the VideoCapture.read(frame) method?

Comment: remove the list.add call, to really just perform the capturing

Comment: @Micka thanks again. Removing the buffer didn't provide any performance boost.

Comment: does your camera work with desired framerate and resolution with different programs like VLC? Maybe full framerate only works with reduced resolution?

Comment: @Micka - Yes, on prebuilt applications, the framerate reaches 20+ FPS at 720p resolution.

Comment: did you try `cam.set(Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);`? What's the codec used by the camera?

Comment: and/or if you reduce the resolution in openCV (e.g. `CAMERA_WIDTH/2` and `CAMERA_HEIGHT/2`); do you reach a higher framerate? You should, if the problem really is the processing speed of `VideoCapture`.

Comment: @Micka - Yes, I set the FPS property for the VideoCapture. And yea, but not by a whole lot. Going all the way down to 320 x 240 only spits out about 18 FPS.